# Обработка форм

Tags: php, html

Есть простое задание: вводится число - количество списков (после ввода списки выводятся). И таких еще 2 ввода. Заполнение списков - неважно. Ввиду незнания Javascript, пытаюсь сделать хоть какое юзабилити. А именно, формы появляются по мере ввода, т.е. ввел - получи следующую.

Первым вариантом было "накопление" кода, т.е. каждый следующий файл содержал все предыдущие + одну новую. Позже решил отказаться от этой идеи, т.к. получилось много файлов (обработчиков) и приходилось много "прикручивать" в скрытые поля формы для передачи через один файл, т.е. понятно что из текущего обработчика я через `$_POST` получу данные, а в следующем уже нет. Решил сделать одним файлом, но передавать данные методом GET (этой страницей будут пользоваться только админы, так что вопросы безопасности можно опустить).

Так вот, как мне заставить ссылку в обработчике формы дописывать параметры GET, а не заменять. Т.е. я хочу накапливать данные в GET. Получаю текущий адрес с параметрами и передаю в форму, а он сразу после имени ставит свои параметры, заменяя предыдущие.

Пример:

```
<form action="index.php?select_1=(не суть)&num_lvl_1=(не суть)" name="abc" method="GET">
```

Получаю: **`index.php?abc=(не суть)`**. А хочу: **`index.php?select_1=(не суть)&num_lvl_1=(не суть)&abc=(не суть)`**. Т.е. чтоб параметры дописывались в конец и не стирали предыдущие.

Как это сделать? Или может предложите свои варианты решения.

Comment: Одним словом - чушь. Ничего не понятно насчет вашей проблемы...

Comment: @Андрей Бакша, у Вас талант объяснять) Почти понятно, что Вы хотите, но неясно чем Вам _POST не угодил. Куда там может что пропасть?

Comment: @Виталий Кустов Ну смотрите. Есть допустим 3 формы => 3 файла-обработчика. На старте есть одна: заполнили. Появилась вторая (другой файл), а в первой должно остаться тоже значение. Сейчас я могу получить его через POST. Получили, заполнили 2-ую форму. Появилась 3-я, т.е. 3-ий файл. Я же не могу получить теперь значение из первой формы через. Надо "прикрутить" его во 2-ой скрытым полем и тащить по всем формам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
<form action="index.php?select_1=(не суть)&num_lvl_1=(не суть)" name="abc" method="GET">
```

Делайте

```
<form action="index.php" name="abc" method="GET">
<input type=hidden name=select_1 value="(не суть)" />
<input type=hidden name=num_lvl_1 value="(не суть)" />
```

Comment: Точно! Спасибо!